# Best way to know if a web page contains only media (only image or only video) content using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a webview object (windows universal) which renders few media content like mp4,images(jpg,png etc). What I wanna do is, I should show up a download button if such media shows up in the browser.
My javascript function below is invoked by the webview and based on the retVal I'm deciding if its media content or not

```
 function()      
 {
     var retVal = '1';
     if(document.doctype == null)
     {

        retVal = '0';
     }
     return retVal;
}
```

//Doctype null => media content is present.
if  tag is present, I would consider it as a normal page.
This works fine for many pages. But still I'm not comfortable with this. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the content type of the media being displayed, *at least gecko, webkit, blink support this property*.

```
function isHtml () {
    return document.contentType === 'text/html'
}
```